# difference between team site and community site and project site sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

Do you have a detailed differences between team site and community site and project site sharepoint 2013?

A comparison cheet sheet will help us for determine which template we would allow to use..

Fast Reply..

Comment: This type of question is not programming related.  It would be better suited on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SharePoint in general, and belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com